# How can I add a wrapper around my nodes?

Tags: 8

How can I wrap my nodes (output in teaser view) in a `<div>` element?

```
<div class="region region-content">
  <h1 class="js-quickedit-page-title page-header">My title</h1>
  // <div class="teasers"> <--- add this
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    ...
  // </div> <--- add this
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the corresponding [twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig) template of your view into your module/theme and name it properly after the view's display, fe. `views--{type, fe. unformatted}--my-view-id--my-block.html.twig`.

Comment: Or even just add a class on the View in the config.